# How to extract subarrays from an array based on threshold values in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of the form:

```
a = numpy.array([0,2,2,3,4,2,5,5,6,2,5,6,4,4,2,3,1,7,7,2,3,3,4,1,8,9,8,8])
threshold = 4
threshold_seq_len = 5
subarray_seq_len = 4
```

the output that I am looking to achieve is

```
b =[array([5,5,6,2,5,6]), array([8,9,8,8])]
```

I would like to extract subarrays based on the criteria:

1) the subarrays should be split based on a sequence of values that are below or equal to *threshold*. In the above case, the first subarray `([5,5,6,2,5,6])` occurs after the sequence `[0,2,2,3,4,2]`, all of which are below or equal to the *threshold* value of 4.

2) the threshold sequences should be at least as long as *threshold_seq_len*, otherwise they would just be part of the subarray. Notice, that the `value '2'` exists in the first subarray because it is a singular occurrence `(length =1)`.

3) The subarrays themselves should be at least as long as *subarray_seq_len*. For example, the the values at indices 17 and 18 are 7 each, but they are not considered since the `length<4`.

For context, the arrays represent amplitudes in an audio file, and I am trying to extract viable non-silence candidates based on the described logic.

What is a pythonic way of achieving this efficiently?

I have tried the approaches described in [Extract subarrays of numpy array whose values are above a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43258896/5858873).

The issue is, that question seems to be a specific case of my problem `(threshold_seq_len=1, subarray_seq_len=1)` since the task involves merely spiltting an array based on the occurrence of threshold values. I have been trying to generalize it but have failed so far.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar Is there a way to not do this as a post-processing step? Timing is key here.

Comment: @Divakar this would filter out the `2` in criteria 2

Comment: Is this a valid subarray? [5,2,5,2,6,2,5,2,6]

Comment: @Ardweaden an edge case that is honestly undesirable, but a fair candidate as per my given logic.

Comment: With `threshold_seq_len = 5`, shouldn't that would have just one subarray?

Comment: No, the [8,9,9,8] comes after a threshold sequence of length 5

Comment: I have an idea, not a solution. I guess you might need a low-pass filter to do the job. I'm not for sure. It'd work if you do not need some kind of accurate results. here it is: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,1,7,7,7]); from scipy.signal import medfilt; medfilt(a, (3,)).astype('int')

Comment: @YunLuo, the low pass filter would return subarrays that are separated by threshold sequences < `threshold_seq_len` though, correct?

Comment: @Melsauce I'll write an answer to explain the idea.

Comment: @Melsauce So, all subarrays that come after the first subarray that has threshold sequence of length 5 are to be considered?

Comment: @Divakar, could you explain further please? Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: @Melsauce I mean, if I append another block of `2,3,3,4,1,8,9,8,8` at the end, should I expect three subarrays as output?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not (unless I'm missing something about my own problem that you've identified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_closing

def filter_ar(a, threshold, threshold_seq_len, subarray_seq_len):
    # Mask wrt threshold
    m0 = np.r_[False,a>threshold,False]

    # Close "holes", those one-off lesser than thresh elements
    k = np.ones(2,dtype=bool)
    m = binary_closing(m0,k)

    # Get initial start, stop indices
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m[:-1] != m[1:])
    s0,s1 = idx[::2],idx[1::2]

    # Masks based on subarray_seq_len, threshold_seq_len
    mask1 = (s1-s0)>=subarray_seq_len
    mask2 = np.add.reduceat(m0,s0) >= threshold_seq_len

    # Get combined one after looking for first sequence that has threshold_seq_len
    # elements > threshold
    mask1[mask2.argmax():] &= True

    # Get valid start,stop indices and then split input array 
    starts,ends = s0[mask1],s1[mask1]
    out = [a[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(starts,ends)]
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

This does work on your example, but I wasn't able to avoid a list comprehension. Also, I haven't checked whether this is slower than simply iterating over a list... (might be)

```
b = np.where(a > threshold)[0]
d = np.where(np.diff(b) >= threshold_seq_len)[0]
e = np.split(b,d+1)

subarrays = [a[i[0]:i[-1]+1] for i in e if (i[-1]-i[0] + 1) >= subarray_seq_len]
```

Comment: the threshold_seq_len is the length of the threshold values. The subarray_seq_len is for the candidates themselves. I edited the example to more clearly illustrate the difference.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid. I still don't understand. I this connected to the number of values below the threshold between two consecutive values above the threshold? I'm simply asking for understanding at this point, if Divakar's code works it's ofc irrelevant.

Comment: No stupid questions. Have a look at the first subaray in the example ([5,5,6,2,5,6]). It occurs after 6 consecutive values that are less than or equal to the threshold value (each less than/equal to value 4). Hence the length (=6) is > *threshold_seq_len* (=5).

On the other hand, the values at indices 16 and 17 are both >*threshold* and also occur after *threshold_seq_len* consecutive values, but are not considered because the length of the subarray (=2) itself is < *subarray_seq_len* (=4).

Hope that's more clear? Happy to explain further.

Comment: Now it's much clearer! Thanks for explaining. Just the final question: why don't the two 7s belong to the first subarray, given there is only a sequence of 4 between the 5,5,6,2,5,6 and 7,7?

Comment: Good point. Edited example so that now there is a sequence of 5 between them (it worked earlier but I forgot to add values in after the first edit).

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code and now it works correctly.